# Jersey: A generic catch all handler for errors?

Tags: java, jersey

Jersey supports ExceptionMappers as a way to generically handle bad things, but that only works if the call reached my code. If someone boffs the URL, say `http://host/fubar` instead of `http://host/foobar`, then it returns a generic 404.

I need to get a hold of those boffed URLs and redirect to a page of my choosing, but after several hours I can't seem to find the right configuration to make that happen. I've been walking through the debugger, but I'm not finding the spot where I'd hook in some configuration to redirect such 404's to a page of my choosing.

Edit: Note that a custom exception mapper for any WebApplicationException is ignored by Jersey (1.17.1). It's instead routed to a different method for handling. Here's the code snippet from Jersey's ContainerResponse.java:

```
if (cause instanceof WebApplicationException) {
    mapWebApplicationException((WebApplicationException)cause);
} else if (!mapException(cause)) { ... }
```

That mapWebApplicationException((WebApplicationException)cause) is Jersey's own handling, so it never hits the mapException(cause) method in the elseif which is where the custom mappers are invoked.

Answer (score 3):

Addressing the bounty:

> This might be a bug in Jersey, as the accepted way to handle exceptions doesn't work for `WebApplicationException`. I'm looking for a work-around, bug report, or information that it's fixed in later versions.

You can create an [`ExceptionMapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) that catches [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) and then test if the exception is an instance of [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html):

```
@Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RuntimeException e) {

        if (e instanceof WebApplicationException) {
            return ((WebApplicationException) e).getResponse();
        }

        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: this should work, we catch everything like this and log a nasty error if someone throws a webapplication exception.

Comment: This still wouldn't make it through the ContainerResponse.java code I mentioned. A boffed URL will never reach my exception mappers, because a boffed URL is a WebApplicationException which is caught in ContainerResponse's first "if"  clause and thus it never makes it to the 2nd else-if block which is where my custom exception mappers would be called. The only solution I can come up with is to have every request hit my server expose a /* REST endpoint, then route internally from there, which then bypasses all the nice @PATH stuff jaxws provides :(

Comment: @ChrisKessel At least such behavior has been fixed in Jersey 2.x.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin What version of Jersey are you using? Have they fixed the bug that the OP mentions in that version?

Comment: @JonRomero I've used many versions of Jersey. I do recommend that you use the most recent version you can. The current one is 2.25.x and the code I posted in my answer works just fine in that version.

Comment: I'm not by a computer today, but when I am I'll upgrade to the latest version. Sounds like that will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a customExceptionMapper should solve this problem.

```
@Provider
public class NotFoundMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException>{

 public Response toResponse(NotFoundException exception){

    // do your custom processing here..
 }

}
```

Comment: Sadly, no. A custom mapper won't be called for any WebApplicationException. ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException, line 398 (ver 1.17.1), looks for that case first and diverts to it's own handler. Only if it's some other type of exception does it look for mapped exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

tried using jersey2.version =2.19 and it works don't know abt 1+ version

demo URL : https://jerseyexample-ravikant.rhcloud.com/rest/jws/getUserList/

you can change it to any thing else and will se below error msg

```
    @Provider
public class EntityNotFoundException  extends WebApplicationException implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException>
{ 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7886520141629139380L;

    //@Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException arg0) {

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder("<response>");
        response.append("<status>ERROR</status>");
        response.append("<message>The method you are looking for does not exist </message>");
        response.append("<time>" + new Date().toString() + "</time>");
        response.append("</response>"); 
        return Response.status(404).entity(response.toString()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
    }


}
```

Comment: There is no need for your `ExceptionMapper` to be an `Exception` itself. So you can get rid of the `extends WebApplicationException`, and better rename it from `EntityNotFoundException` to `NotFoundExceptionMapper`.